# json php script running out when pulling big data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a query with 4000 object type of data needs to be pulled out and form a json result. When I run within 400 number of data, it's fine. But when I want to pull out more data. It gave me blank page - I suppose that the php is just stopped executing. But what I had waited is only 10 - 20 seconds. The time out setting might not be the issue. Is it something about memory. So I changed memory_limit to 512M and tried again, still, no change.

```
max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60     ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 512M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
```

Then I wonder if it's mysql related but I really don't know what to change...

```
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
```

I am on testing box so CPU, RAM won't be the issue.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question as asked, but you could keep memory usage low by printing the outer JSON array manually:

```
echo "[";
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($first)
        $first = false;
    else
        echo ",";
    echo json_encode($row);
}
echo "]\n";
```

Comment: the memory footprints are big? I am using Drupal so I hardly think of going to change the code. That might be last resort

Answer (score 1):

Set error reporting level to maximum:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

This will help you with understanding the problem

Comment: still blank page. Even 2 known notice error which I always got are not displaying

Comment: Nothing is displayed. The known notices are not relevant.